# Application of Baire Category theorem in $C[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, baire-category

Let $f_n\in C[0, 1]$. Assume that for every $x\in [0, 1]$ there exists a finite limit $f(x) = \lim f_n(x)$. Apply the Baire category theorem to the sets
$$ A_n = \{x : |f_m(x) - f_n(x)| \leq \frac{1}{3} ,  \forall m > n\}$$
to prove that f cannot be the salt and pepper function
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
1 & \text{if} \ x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ 
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{matrix}\right.$$

I have to show that the metric space $C[0, 1]$  cannot be written as the countable union of closed , no where dense sets. So the set $A_n$ as given must be proven that is closed , nowhere dense.  Right? (I don't know how to approach any of these requirements)

how to show the second part?

Also the function g is not continuous, so it does not belong to $C[0,1]$. What is the role of it in the question?

Comment: what is the norm that youa re using in $C[0,1]$?

Comment: Application of Baire: The sets $A_n$ are closed and $\bigcup_nA_n = [0,1]$. Hence, there is $n_0$ such that $A_{n_0}$ has non-empty interior.

Comment: @Masacroso If nothing else is said $C[0,1]$ always is equipped with the infinity-norm.

Comment: @amsmath but then the exercise is trivial because $C[0,1]$ is complete, and then it is not possible that the Dirichlet function is a limit of some Cauchy sequence in $C[0,1]$

Comment: @Masacroso Note that $f_n\to f$ pointwise!

Comment: @stat_yale Can you use my hint? It means that there is a subinterval $I\subset [0,1]$ on which $f$ differs only by maximally $1/3$ from some fixed (continuous) $f_n$.

Comment: @amsmath , no actually, I did not get your hint for showing nowhere dense part. Also , how about showing that $C[0,1]$, cannot be written as the countable of those?

Comment: @stat_yale because $C[0,1]$ is complete with the supremum norm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $A_n = \bigcap_{m>n}(f_n-f_m)^{-1}([-1/3,1/3])$, and hence $A_n$ is closed for each $n$. Moreover, for each $x\in [0,1]$, as $(f_n(x))_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence for each $x$, there exists $n$ such that $x\in A_n$. So, $\bigcup_nA_n = [0,1]$. By Baire's theorem, there exists $n_0$ such that $A_{n_0}$ has a non-empty interior; so, there exists an open interval $I\subset A_{n_0}$. Thus, for $x\in I$ we have $|f_m(x)-f_{n_0}(x)|\le 1/3$ for all $m>n_0$. In particular (letting $m\to\infty$),
$$
|f(x)-f_{n_0}(x)|\le 1/3\quad\text{for all $m>n_0$ and all $x\in I$.}
$$
Now, choose $x_0\in I$ irrational. Assume that $f(x_0) = 0$. That means that $f_{n_0}(x_0)\in [-1/3,1/3]$. Because $f_{n_0}$ is continuous, for $x$ in a neighborhood $J$ of $x_0$ we have $f_{n_0}(x)\in (-2/3,2/3)$. Choose some rational $x_1\in J$. Then
$$
|f(x_1)|\le|f(x_1)-f_{n_0}(x_1)|+|f_{n_0}(x_1)| < 1/3+2/3 = 1,
$$
so $f(x_1)\neq 1$. So, $f$ cannot be the salt-and-pepper function.

Comment: Two questions; 1) why we want to write $\bigcup_nA_n = [0,1]$? This gives us what? 2) I also did not understand this part; each $x\in[0,1]$, as $\{f_n(x)\}_{n∈N}$ is a Cauchy sequence for each x, there exists n such that $x\in A_n$. gives, $\bigcup_nA_n = [0,1]$.

Comment: (1) It gives us that one of the sets has non-empty interior. (2) Well, let $x\in [0,1]$ be arbitrary. Then $(f_n(x))_n$ is a Cauchy sequence. Thus, there exists $n$ such that for all $m,k\ge n$ we have $|f_k(x)-f_m(x)|\le 1/3$. In particular, $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|\le 1/3$ holds for all $m>n$. So, $x\in A_n$.